# Unable to connect to Bluetooth service from chrome

Tags: bluetooth, web-bluetooth

I am trying to write a web app to control the target power of my Kickr Core turbo trainer.
I spent far too long trying to connect to the `fitness_machine` profile before realising that my trainer does not support this. Instead it uses a custom kickr profile and I managed to find some docs on it [here](https://docplayer.net/42079050-Wahoo-fitness-equipment-profile.html).

The uuids listed (`A026EE07-0A7D-4AB3-97FAF1500F9FEB8B` for Wahoo Fitness Equipment Service) do match what I see when I look at chrome://bluetooth-internals after a bit of formatting: `a026ee07-0a7d-4ab3-97fa-f1500f9feb8b`.

I am not able to connect to this service though. If I use this uuid to `requestDevice({filters: [uuid]})` then no devices are listed in the connection dialog. If I acceptAllDevices: `requestDevice({ acceptAllDevices: true, optionalServices: [uuid] })` then I see my trainer listed but when I select it I am not able to connect to the service, I am told that the service does not exist.

What else can I try to get connected to my trainer? (I am really regretting not getting a trainer that supports the standard Bluetooth profile now but nothing can be done about that now!)

Comment: have you tried to request device in this way: navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({filters: [{services: [uuid]}]}) ?

Comment: yes, If I do that then no devices appear in the select device dialog.

Comment: When you connect to this device from `chrome://bluetooth-internals`, can you see the Wahoo Fitness Equipment Service and read/write characteristics?

Comment: yes but when I try to use those details to connect or list devices I don't see any devices or I get an when trying to connect.